# Localization in FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

I'm using FolderBrowserDialog in a WPF application, and I need to implement localization on it so the buttons of the dialog would be in the correcr lenguage.

How can I do that? Is there a free control somewhere that can help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75595459/why-isnt-the-folderbrowserdialog-windows-forms-localized-after-programmatical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx) and [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) to the desired language:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
```

[This](http://www.siao2.com/2007/01/11/1449754.aspx) blog article offers some more information.