# Why isn't the FolderBrowserDialog (Windows Forms) localized after programmatically setting the culture?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, localization

I'm showing the `FolderBrowserDialog` from a WPF application, and the thread's culture properties have been set like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es");
```

Yet the window title and buttons of the dialog are in English. The rest of the application is correctly using the Spanish resource strings. The only way I can get the folder browser dialog to be in Spanish is if I go to Windows Settings and change the language to Spanish. However, I shouldn't have to do this if I'm using the code above. Am I missing something else?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1180093/Localization-for-Common-Dialogs-in-Winform

Comment: Hmm, [this identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19250242/3744182) from 2013 never got a proper answer.  @HansPassant or redcurry, do you want to add an answer?  If not I could add a community wiki answer and close that one as a duplicate.

Comment: Since I didn't have answer myself, I'll leave it to @HansPassant to answer it (if he wants).